# How to change the Dropbox sync folder location programmatically on OSX

Tags: macos, dropbox, dropbox-api

is there a possibility to change the Dropbox sync folder (aka "Dropbox location") programmatically on Mac OSX? By programmatically I mean by executing some command line helper tool or by using the Dropbox API.

I've searched around for this quite a long while now, but couldn't find any satisfying answers. 
Sym-linking or using an alternative cloud provider (with a possibly better CLI/API) as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/575550/how-do-i-change-the-dropbox-directory-on-a-headless-gnu-linux-server) are not an option for me.

As I understand the Dropbox API, it is made for accessing the Dropbox Server storage from within one's own application rather than interacting with the "out-of-the-box" Desktop sync client, is this correct?

The solution I am looking for should also work very reliably, so "hacking" the encrypted SQLite dbx files (as suggested [here](http://0b4af6cdc2f0c5998459-c0245c5c937c5dedcca3f1764ecc9b2f.r43.cf2.rackcdn.com/12058-woot13-kholia.pdf)) or an Apple UI script that changes the sync folder via the Dropbox UI Desktop client are also really not an option for me.

For Google Drive I know that doing this is a simple as stopping the sync client, moving the sync folder, changing the sync path in the sync_config.db accordingly and re-starting the Desktop sync app. -- Exactly such a procedure is what I would also be hoping to find for Dropbox :-)

THX for your replies & suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without using the potentially brittle methods you mentioned, I don't believe there's a way to do this programmatically.

Your understanding of the Dropbox API is correct though. Using the API allows you to communicate with the Dropbox servers directly to interact with the account, and not the local desktop client.